# Check range of times in excel to ensure they are within core hours

Tags: excel, time

I am trying to check to see if the following Times in the picture fall within a certain core hour of 0930 - 1430, in military time.  This breaks because you aren't clocked in at 930 therefore missed a half an hour of core time.

Currently I am using min/max to check for those columns which works until this example.  Any ideas would be great!

Here is an example:

[image: Table Example]

Here is what the output should look like (even though the math is wrong.

[image: Table Example]

It should say CR Missed=1.5 (Core Hour starts at 930 and clock in was 11).

The current code I am using

```
=IF(AND(COUNTA(J8:J12)<>0,COUNTA(K8:K12)<>0),IF(AND($AQ$15>=MIN(J8:J12),$AR$15<=MAX(K8:K12)),"","CR Missed = "),"")
```

Edit:  Sums are not relevant (it just adds the times)  AQ=0930 and AR=1430 (The range of "Core Hours")

Essentially you can enter in different times in each row and I am trying to make sure that you are 'logged in' between required times of 0930 and 1430.  Currently the Min/Max equation works ish but doesnt cover the shown example where I am actually missing 30 mins (logged out at 0900 and logged back in at 1000).

I feel like I am missing some logic or command.  Sorry, I hope this helps.

From Comments and to add clarity, added an example of the ouput

1. There can be more lines; I have up to 5 (Just hidden)
2. The times dont have to be in order but generally thats how they would be entered.
3. No these are technically different time codes (Leave/Sick/Regular) You would not overlap Sick and Leave for example

---

**Solved**

I would like to thank everyone for the help!

The function I ended up using was Ron's example with a twist.  As his example showed how many hours worked that were within a time range; I wanted to show how many were missing; and since multiple check ins/outs could happen I just covered all the available slots.

```
=ABS((5-(MAX(MIN(EndTime,K9)-MAX(StartTime,J9),0)*24))-(5-(MAX(MIN(EndTime,K10)-MAX(StartTime,J10),0)*24)))
```

So this will give me the number of missed hours between required time interval with multiple check in and check outs.

[image: Solved Example]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what is supposed to happen, what does your `IF` statement do currently? Are the sums relevant or not? Also, what are AQ15 and AR15 referring to?

Comment: I updated my main post but basically that code is supposed to show "Missed Core Hours", if your entered times do not cover 0930-1430 interval, if you arent missing them then it shows up blank

Comment: Okay, so each and every minute between 9:30 to 14:30 needs to be covered by "RG", "TS" and "LG". And because there's a gap between 9:00 and 10:00, 30 minutes are not "core hours". Okay, I will give it another attempt.

Comment: More info required: Can there be more (or less) than 3 lines of times? Are they always in time order?  Can a lines start time be before the previous lines end time?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity
1.) There can be more lines; I have up to 5 (Just hidden)

2.) The times dont have to be in order but generally thats how they would be entered.  
3.) No these are technically different time codes (Leave/Sick/Regular) You would not overlap Sick and Leave for example

Answer (score 0):

## Preface

My approach was to look for the first time-slot that covered the starting time (9:30).

If we find a time-slot like (7:00 - 10:00), we need to check if the next time slot starts at 10:00.

If the next time slot covers 10:00, we will check this time slot's end time with the next one.

And we repeat this process until all time-slots have been checked. If the time we end up with is greater than your "core end time" (14:30), then we know that all hours of the core hours have been covered continuously without breaks (might even be more).

On the contrary, if it is smaller, the value we ended up with, is the last point in time that they worked continuously without any gaps.

## Formulas & Explanations

[image]

- Insert start time into D1, and end time in E1.
- In C2 and downwards is: `=IF(AND($B2>$D1;$D1>=A2);$B2;$D1)`

  *This is what checks if the time we were looking for was in this interval, if it was, this value will change into the end time of the time slot. If not, it will remain as the previous - this is what lets us know not all core hours have been covered.*
- D2 and downwards is simply: `=MAX(D1;C2)` (This could be included in C1, but for readability and to easier understand, I made it a separate column.
- Finally `E4`, whether or not all core hours have been covered is: `=C4>=E1`, which becomes `TRUE` or `FALSE`. If you want the "CR Missed", that will be a simple: `=IF(E4;"";"CR Missed")`

I realize this isn't very dynamic, so if you have more time slots, you will have to copy the formula down further.

So, maybe this won't be the ultimate solution, but rather do the job and perhaps be enough for you to expand upon.

*Best regards!* ^_^

Comment: First off! Thank you for the input! Im playing around with it right now.  I am trying to include this check in one line if possible.  One thing, I am guessing your semicolons in the code are supposed to be commas?

Comment: Glad to hear. Yeah, depending on your Excel version, you may or may not be able to fit it into 1 cell. But like I mentioned, you could move the `MAX()` into the `C `-column. Regarding the semi colons, because I'm Swedish, I use commas to denote decimals. So to separate parameters, we use semi-colons instead. So you just replace those with commas and it will be all fine :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you want for output.  Perhaps this will get you started.

To compute the hours from `Start`=> `End` that fall within a certain range (eg: `Core Time`):

```
=MAX(MIN(TIME(14,30,0),End)-MAX(TIME(9,30,0),Start),0)
```

So you could do something like:

[image]

Comment: This was the one that got me on the right track.  I think my issue was my approach originally.  I was going from ALL the Start Times (Finding the Min) and all the End Times (Finding the Max) which stumped me

Thank you for your time!  This got me the approach I needed: I will edit my main post to show the modification.

Comment: @AdamZeid  If you want to calculate the missing Core hours, just subtract.  Something like `=5/24-sum(Core)` *(Excel stores time as fractions of a day. So `5/24 = 5 hours`)*